# Как сделать чтобы в Qt Creator'е при создании проекта (под управлением CMake), приложение запускалось в отдельном окне консоли

Tags: c++, qtcreator

А не в самом окошке IDE (Вывод приложения)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде CMake здесь ни при чём. Настройка, какой терминал использовать, тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление**

Вполне возможно, что нужно в настройках самого проекта внести какие-нибудь изменения, типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня Qt Creator 2.5.2 и к тому же виндовый, в моем нет такой настройки как вы показали. Самое любопытное когда компилируешь код компилятором от майкрософт то все нормально запускается в отдельном терминале. а если в MinGw то вывод идет в IDE

Comment: @perfect , обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо хороший человек помогло! ура у меня теперь есть хороший компилятор!